# IP was blocked even allow order

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

I have protected my database PHPMYADMIN. I try to do like:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny From All
    Allow from 10.230.35.xx -> my IP
    Allow from 10.230.35.X2  -> additional IP it works
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>
```

But,my access was blocked even I allowed.Why?
I am trying to add another IP, and it works but not for my IP.

Comment: Try adding this line: `Order deny,allow`

Comment: Already, I put it before Deny From All but still same. do restart apache2 still same.

Comment: You are relying on IP-based ACLs to protect youself from being compromised via phpmyadmin?  The best thing to do, in a professional environment, is to get rid of that (and other web control panels) and learn SQL.  Seriously.

Comment: @FalconMomot:so, what is the best way?

Comment: The best way is to get rid of it, and manage your DBMS using SQL and the SQL command line.

Comment: how to do that in ubuntu server? sorry i'm not an expert.

Comment: And that is why you're denied. Because you're trying to permit access to your private IP address (10.x.x.x) and you're actually accessing it via proxy (136.x.x.x). It wouldn't make sense to permit access to your proxy address though.

Comment: @alex: Ahh,I see. problem solved. I forget to add my proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that you will only be able to access this stuff over IPv4; if you end up using IPv6 somehow, it will deny you.  If you have dynamic DNS updates in your environment, hosts supporting IPv6 will often register their IPv6 addresses and then prefer them and start communicating over IPv6 all on their own.  See if that is the cause of your trouble.

Try looking at your access log and error log, and see what IP address is getting the 403 error that is being sent.

Comment: I have checked my network setting, my IP is in IPv4

Comment: show `[error] [client 136.198.117.xx] client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/`.136.198.117.xx this is ip proxy  for internet access in my office. but i couldn't access my phpmyadmin at 136.198.117.x.

Comment: That'd do it.  You should create exclusions for local addresses if you are using a proxy.